# Change linux service to start in namespace on boot instead of just starting normal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

Is it possible to tell an application to start in a Network Namespace on boot, instead of just starting normal? I'm running transmission-daemon on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It boots at startup, which is great, I just need it to start in a namespace instead. I have my namespace being created using pre-up in the /etc/network/interfaces file. It seems like the most efficient way would be just to alter what is already making the service to start on boot to begin with, but I could be wrong.

Comment: David: Specifically, a _network_ namespace? There are six different kinds of namespaces on Linux.

Comment: @Karan: Based on earlier questions I'm guessing [this kind](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) of [namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/) – where specific processes can see different network interfaces, or different process trees, or such.

Comment: @grawity @Karan I should have been a lot more specific, pure laziness. I will update my question. Network Namespace. `ip netns exec vpn service transmission-daemon start`. I guess I could just have that run on boot, but that seems like a very nasty way to do it. To to mention, I would have to make sure it is run after the namespace is created. Which is why I was wondering if there was a way to do it by just altering what was already making it start on boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The "start on boot" part:

Write an Upstart service config and put it in `/etc/init`. The [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) has examples. Alternatively, modify the existing `transmission.conf` if there is one.

For future Ubuntu releases (15.04 and later), you'll need to use systemd though. Write a `transmission.service` and put it in `/etc/systemd/system`.

#### The "…in a netns" part:

Checking the [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/), there are no related settings (beyond a simple chroot). Most existing Upstart init scripts indeed still rely on external tools for such tasks, so `ip netns` is fine.

The same currently applies to systemd. While it has [JoinsNamespaceOf=](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#JoinsNamespaceOf=), you can only specify another service unit, and not yet a named namespace.

Comment: Well $%^& me. LOL. Thank you very much for answering my question. I guess I'll just attempt to modify the `original transmission-daemon.conf`. :D

Comment: I should have also linked to http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files for that case.

Comment: Please provide the service script. Because it is not as easy as you write here. Because the service starts transmission with its own user (who does not have access to netns by the way).